# Jquery mobile full site link loads full site, but links there go to mobile site

Tags: jquery-mobile, redirect

I think I've looked over 50 different examples online, but can't find the same problem.

I've got a jquery mobile site and a full site (it's a WordPress site). I've put the following code in the header.php file of the full site:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function urlParam(name){
                var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                if(results)
                    return results[1] || 0;
                else
                    return '';
            }

            if(urlParam('view') == 'full'){ 
            }
            if(urlParam('view') == ''){
                // <![CDATA[
                var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
                if (mobile) { 
                        document.location = "http://mysite.com/mobile/index.html";  
                }  
                // ]]>
            }
    </script>
```

This works fine and when I load the full site on my iphone it redirects to the mobile version.

However, I have a link to the full site on my mobile site like so:

```
    <li><a href="http://albariancoins.com/?view=full" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Full Site</a></li>
```

When I click this link it DOES take me to the full site, but if I click on any links on the full site, I get redirected back to the mobile site.

FYI, I've tried (and failed) setting cookies. All the scripts I've used haven't worked (I'm sure it's my fault) and I end up stuck in a continuous redirect.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you only need the statement: if(urlParam('view') != 'full'){ check if mobile and redirect.. }

I suggest you use document.write(urlParam('view')); to check what urlParam('view') actually returns. This should make it easier for you to debug. Though the best way to debug is to use chrome or firefox tools.